# Ubuntu 19.10 screen glitch

Tags: graphics, 19.10, amd-graphics, visual-artifacts

I tried to solve the login loop issue this morning, and reinstalled the gdm3 package:

```
sudo apt-get purge gdm3
sudo apt-get install gdm3
```

After rebooting my screen with GUI now looks like this, but tty3 console looks normal.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gycKJ.jpg]

I've got monitor: acer v193hqv and graphics card: Radeon X1600
xrandr shows current resolution 1366x768 and 59.69 refresh rate.

UPD: entering `startx` didn't work, with `xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)` error

full log is available here https://pastebin.com/Gn2rZGPE

(WW) warnings and (EE) errors are as follows:

```
[   166.203] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   166.203]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   166.203] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   166.203]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   166.203] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   166.203]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   166.203] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   166.203]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   166.203] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   166.203]    Entry deleted from font path.

[   167.651] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[   167.651] (II) [KMS] Kernel modesetting enabled.
[   167.651] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[   167.651] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev

[   167.754] (EE) open /dev/fb0: Permission denied
[   167.754] (WW) VGA arbiter: cannot open kernel arbiter, no multi-card support

[   168.035] (WW) RADEON(0): 3 ZaphodHeads crtcs unavailable. Some outputs will stay off.
```

Comment: Log into TTY terminal, type `startx` and hit enter. Does your desktop appeared? If yes, is it OK? If no, what is wrong?

Comment: at first just `startx` didn't work, but `sudo startx` worked. Desktop appeared, it is OK. so i've got one desktop working by `ctrl+alt+f3` and another desktop giltching by `ctrl+alt+f7`

Comment: You executed `sudo startx` ?! Log out from desktop. Running session as root is dangerous.

Comment: I did it to test my hardware is ok. so now I'm sure it's software problem. when I did `startx` as user, I received this log file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oyAw8YTj5zekkm8VsG0hB2OR9S-p4RuO/view?usp=sharing
this error I see on screen when server terminates xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)

Comment: Edit your question with the log. I can't see log from Google Drive. All details should be at question description, not in any external site.

Comment: done. thanks for helping me by the way, I really appreciate it

Comment: I tried to purge gdm3 and lightdm without reinstalling. after rebooting I managed to run `startx` as current user and finally saw normal desctop 
but after reinstalling gdm3 problem returned